# Do separation vectors exist in general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, vectors, covariance

Deriving the equation of geodesic deviation one looks at two test masses on positions $x^\mu$ und $\tilde{x}^\mu$ and defines the separation vector $\boldsymbol{\chi}$ as

$$\tilde{x}^\mu=x^\mu+\chi^\mu$$

I don't really understand how this can be a vector since I have been told that vectors can only exist in one tangent space at one point of curved spacetime. That (so I was told as well) is the reason why one has to carfully parallel transport vectors from one point to another when defining the covariant derivative. How then can a vector point from one point to another through curved spacetime?

Comment: I think the common idea is that these two coordinates describe infinitesimally spaced trajectories. The deviation/separation can then be seen as a tangent vector (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_deviation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is addressed by Carroll in section 3.10 of "Spacetime and Geometry".

The idea is that, in order to formalize the idea of two "infinitesimally close" geodesics separating we can consider a one-parameter family of geodesics $\gamma_s (t)$; the parameter $t$ moves along each geodesic, the parameter $s$ moves us between geodesics.
Then, the separation vector can be defined as a regular tangent vector: the derivative of the position with respect to $s$.

Comment: Thanks! I did need some time, but I think I understand now :)